# Sending sms and switching sim cards with react native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I would like to send sms and switch sim cards from which i send from time to time, is there a way to do it with expo?
Or react native way if no expo libaries

Answer (score 1):

No, You can only open  the default UI/app for sending SMS messages with prefilled addresses and message.